# Compression of sequence of integers providing random access

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a sequence of n integers in a small range `[0,k)` and all the integers have the same frequency `f` (so the size of the sequence is `n=f∗k`). What I'm trying to do now is to compress this sequence while providing *random access* (what is the i-th integer). The time to achieve random access doesn't have to be O(1). I'm more interested in achieving high compression at the expense of higher random access times.

I haven't tried with Huffman coding since it assigns codes based on frequencies (and all my frequencies are the same). Perhaps I'm missing some simple encoding for this particular case.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Already asked in cs.stackexchange, but asking here also for better coverage, sorry.

Comment: I cannot imagine how you can compress this while retaining guaranteed O(1) random access. Are you willing to accept worse algorithmic performance rather than just a worse constant multiplier with O(1) performance?

Comment: Yes, I accept worse time for the random accesses, they don't have to be O(1). I'm striving for high compression with *decent* random access time.

Comment: Is the sequence compressible or is the data random? Frequencies of single integers may be the same but could a sub-sequence (say 1,2,3) occur more often than others?

Comment: If the sequence is truly random then you pretty much can't compress it.  You can use a minimum size representation for each integer of log2(k) bits but beyond that you're at the mercy of entropy.

Comment: @evilotto: The integers are in the range `[0, k)`, so they are already in the minimum size representation. However we 're not talking about a random sequence by any stretch of the imagination since all of them have the exact same frequency.

Comment: If `k = 256` and the data is completely random I would expect each to have (mostly?) the same frequency. Given an 8-bit representation per integer I'd say its uncompressible without some other source of redundancy.

Comment: So the distribution is not random (same frequency for each number), but is the order random or structured? e.g. 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 is compressible, but a truly random rearrangement of that not so much (at least in the long run). Structure in the stream can potentially lead to more compression than just considering frequency, even in extremely skewed distributions.

Comment: @jplot How did you get 0.00255 as entropy?

Comment: @jkraju The formula is sum `n_c / n * lg(n / n_c)` for all `c`, where `n_c` is the frequency of `c` and `n` is the length of the sequence. In this case `n_c` is `n / k` for all `c`.

Comment: But that formula evaluates to 7.

Comment: @jkraju Yes, I made a huge *silly* mistake. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your integers have the same frequency, then a fair approximation to optimal compression will be `ceil(log2(k))` bits per integer.  You can access a bit-array of these in constant time.

If `k` is painfully small (like 3), the above method may waste a fair amount of space.  But, you can combine a fixed number of your small integers into a base-`k` number, which can fit more efficiently into a fixed number of bits (you may also be able to fit the result conveniently into a standard-sized word).  In any case, you can also access this coding in constant time.

If your integers *don't* have the same frequency, optimal compression may yield variable bit rates from different parts of your input, so the simple array access won't work.  In that case, good random-access performance would require an index structure:  break your compressed data into convenient sized chunks, which can each be decompressed sequentially, but this time is bounded by the chunk size.

---

If the frequency of each number is *exactly* the same, you may be able to save some space by taking advantage of this -- but it may not be enough to be worthwhile.

The entropy of `n` random numbers in range `[0,k)` is `n log2(k)`, which is `log2(k)` bits per number; this is the number of bits it takes to encode your numbers *without* taking advantage of the exact frequency.

The entropy of distinguishable permutations of `f` copies each of `k` elements (where `n=f*k`) is:

```
log2( n!/(f!)^k ) = log2(n!) - k * log2(f!)
```

Applying Stirling's approximation (which is good here only if `n` and `f` are large), yields:

```
~ n log2(n) - n log2(e) - k ( f log2(f) - f log2(e) )
= n log2(n) - n log2(e) - n log2(f) + n log2(e)
= n ( log2(n) - log2(f) )
= n log2(n/f)
= n log2(k)
```

What this means is that, if `n` is large and `k` is small, you will not gain a significant amount of space by taking advantage of the exact frequency of your input.

The total error from the Stirling approximation above is `O(log2(n) + k log2(f))`, which is `O(log2(n)/n + log2(f)/f)` per number encoded.  This does mean that if your `k` is so large that your `f` is small (i.e., each distinct number only has a small number of copies), you may be able to save some space with a clever encoding.  However, the question specifies that `k` is, in fact, small.

Comment: Compressing numbers in the range [0,k) to ceil(log2 k) bits will provide the same "compression" regardless of the frequency of the numbers, although the bit-field manipulations are a bit painful. In fact, if you knew k was small relative to, say, 2^64, you could get somewhat closer to an optimal compression by storing floor(log(k) 2^64) numbers in base k in 64-bit integer. The rest of the analysis is spot-on.

Comment: That last was what I was trying for in my second paragraph.

Comment: And I have improved the third paragraph to explain that I was talking about a different case.

Comment: +1. By the way, you can compute the theoretical best compression ratio easily: (lgamma(f * k + 1) - k * lgamma(f + 1))/(f * k * log(k)). Plotting that shows how quickly the returns drop off.

Comment: Could you share the insight of your formula ? @comingstorm So, all in all I can't improve the log2(k) bits per integer ?

Comment: Right.  As long as `k` is a small fixed value, the best possible data rate tends to `log2(k)` bits per integer as your input size `n` increases.  For an input of `n` integers, the maximum *total* number of bits that can be saved (over `n log2(k)` for the whole input) is O(log n).

Comment: @jplot, it's just standard combinatorics. lgamma(i + 1) is i factorial (and lgamma is the log of gamma). The number of arrangements of f copies of each of k things is f*k!/f!^k, so the log of that is lgamma(f*k+1) - k*lgamma(f+1), which is the numerator. If you just form the stream by concatenating all the numbers base k, you require space proportional to f*k*log(k), which is the denominator. (To get space in bits in both cases, you'd want to use log2, but since I'm dividing to get a ratio, I just use whatever consistent log base is most convenient, which is e).

Answer (score 1):

If you work out the number of possible different combinations and take its log base 2 you can find the best possible compression, and I don't think it will be that great in your case. With 16 numbers of frequency 1 the number of possible messages is 16! and Excel tells me log base 2 of 16! is 44.25, whereas storing them as 4-bit codes would only take 64 bits. (where there is more than one of each kind you want http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html)

I think you will have a problem mixing random access into this because the only information you have is that there are fixed numbers of each type of element - in the whole sequence. That's not a lot of information for the whole sequences, and it says almost nothing about the first half of the sequence in isolation, because you could well have more of some number in the first half and less in the second half.