# Practical Compression of Random Data

Tags: algorithm, compression, gzip

So yesterday I asked a question on compression of a sequence of integers ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517580/compression-of-sequence-of-integers-providing-random-access)) and most comments had a similar point: if the order is random (or worst, the data is completely random) then one have to settle down with log2(k) bits for a value k. I've also read similar replies in other questions on this site. Now, I hope this isn't a silly question, if I take that sequence and serialize it to a file and then I run *gzip* on this file then I do achieve compression (and depending on the time I allow *gzip* to run I might get high compression). Could somebody explain this fact ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for a given compressor there exists a set of inputs which will be compressed and a set of inputs which won't be compressed ; that's true for any compression program (gzip included). What does not exists is a perfect compressor which for any input yields a compressed output (easily proved). Say we have a random sequence generator, it could produce n times the same number, and even a compressor based on RLE would compress this sequence efficiently.

Comment: You wrote _serialized_, if you wrote a file containing only characters '0' to '9'  (10 different characters) any actual compression program will be able to compress it, at least by half i guess

Comment: Upvoting your question because it's not silly, it is a legitimate question. Your hesitation at compressing random data ad infinitum clearly shows you've tried to understand the question well enough to notice and be concerned about the contradiction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you're achieving compression on your random file because you're not using an optimal serialization technique, but without more details it's impossible to answer your question. Is the compressed file with n numbers in the range [0, k) less than n*log2(k) bits? (That is, n*log256(k) bytes). If so, does gzip manage to do that for all the random files you generate, or just occasionally?

Let me note one thing: suppose you say to me, "I've generated a file of random octets by using a uniform_int_distribution(0, 255) with the mt19937 prng [1]. What's the optimal compression of my file?" Now, my answer could reasonably be: "probably about 80 bits". All I need to reproduce your file is

- the value you used to seed the prng, quite possibly a 32-bit integer [2]; and
- the length of the file, which probably fits in 48 bits.

And if I can reproduce the file given 80 bits of data, that's the optimal compression. Unfortunately, that's not a general purpose compression strategy. It's highly unlikely that gzip will be able to figure out that you used a particular prng to generate the file, much less that it will be able to reverse-engineer the seed (although these things are, at least in theory, achievable; the Mersenne twister is not a cryptographically secure prng.)

For another example, it's generally recommended that text be compressed before being encrypted; the result will be quite a bit shorter than compressing after encryption. But the fact is that encryption adds very little entropy; at most, it adds the number of bits in the encryption key. Nonetheless, the resulting output is difficult to distinguish from random data, and gzip will struggle to compress it (although it often manages to squeeze a few bits out).

---

Note 1: Note: that's all c++11/boost lingo. mt19937 is an instance of the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) pseudo-random number generator (prng), which has a period of 2^19937 - 1.

Note 2: The state of the Mersenne twister is actually 624 words (19968 bits), but most programs use somewhat fewer bits to seed it. Perhaps you used a 64-bit integer instead of a 32-bit integer, but it doesn't change the answer by much.

Comment: If you use /dev/random, then the data is really random.  It is not generated by a pseudo-random process, and so there is no seed for compression.  It works by collecting entropy from random events in the operating system.

Comment: @MarkAdler, sure. Did I deny that? I'm just mentioning that the concept of "optimal compression" has some interesting corner cases, of which pseudo-random number generators are one. Indeed, you could use /dev/random, but you would probably find it pretty expensive to use as a source of test data for gzip. (Entropy is not cheap.) If you use /dev/urandom, it's not "really" random. If you use /dev/random to produce a seed (the more normal case), then there is a seed and we're back to optimal compression being the size of the seed, max 19968 bits (for mt19937).

Comment: I was simply providing information for the reader of this question.  The question was about random data, not pseudo-random data, and I was noting that many systems have a source for such data.  By the way, I use /dev/random for testing all the time, and it doesn't seem expensive.  For the amounts of data I generate, it never seems to run out of random data in the pool.  I have never seen a speed difference between /dev/random and /dev/urandom.  (/dev/urandom draws from the entropy pool until it runs out, and only then switches to a pseudo-random generator.)  I pull millions of bytes at a time.

Comment: @MarkAdler, I guess your machine has a lot more entropy than my little laptop, then. I just tried pulling 160 bytes out of /dev/random (with dd) and the command locked up until I waved the mouse around for 10 seconds. I've seen lots of Apache instances block on startup because of lack of entropy for initializing SSL, when set to use /dev/random. Clearly YMMV (and also that of others reading this comment).

Comment: I had assumed incorrectly that Mac OS X implemented those devices with the same requirements, but it does not.  The reason I've never seen a difference between random and urandom is that in Mac OS X, they are different names for the same thing.  They are a pseudo-random generator that is reseeded frequently from entropy that comes from random jitter measurements of the kernel.  Thank you for your performance information that prompted me to read my documentation.

Answer (score 4):

> if I take that sequence and serialize it to a file and then I run gzip
>   on this file then I do achieve compression

What is "it"?  If you take random *bytes* (each uniformly distributed in 0..255) and feed them to gzip or any compressor, you may on very rare occasions get a small amount of compression, but most of the time you will get a small amount of expansion.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is truly random, on average no compression algorithm can compress it. But if the data has some predictable patterns (for e.g. if the probability of a symbol is dependent on the previous k-symbols occurring in the data), many (prediction-based) compression algorithms will succeed.

Comment: This is wrong. random generated data is most likely to contain pattern - the thing is - you cannot predict what these patterns will be.

Comment: I don't think so, unless you are implying that the pattern comes because of pseudo-randomness. But then such patterns are very difficult to detect (at least I don't think there is any compression algorithm that can take advantage of this).

Comment: This is a purely probabilistic issue. Similar to the birthday paradox (the probability of 2 people out of 24 to have the birthday in the same day is greater then 0.5). Even though each pattern has slim probability to repeat - there are a lot of possible patterns, and the probability of one of them to occur increases exponantially with the length of the string - so the odds are - one of them will occur.

Comment: @amit Again, there obviously will be *some* repetition (if that was forbidden it wouldn't be random), but it needs more than *some* to outweigh the compression overhead. Three repetitions (of which you can only omit 2) of a 6-bit pattern, out of 100 bits total, give you 12 bits of saved storage *at best*. And this specific pattern repeating another three times per 100 bits you generate is **much** less than any pattern occurring more than once.

Comment: FYI: I ran a random string generator, and found out that with probability ~5.6*10^-18 (under wilcoxon test) - gzip reduces the size of the file.

Comment: More precisely, any compression algorithm's expected compression ratio on fully random data can't be less than 1. Individual examples can compress well, however. It is just that any algorithm is more likely to expand than compress fully random data.

Comment: @KeithRandall: This claim does not add well with the test I ran, care to explain it? (You can read the deleted answer, and reproduce the experiment if you wish to)

Comment: @amit: your test isn't right.  Your `FileWriter` is using the default character encoding, so you're not getting 16 bits of data written to the file for every 16-bit `char` you're writing.  You're only writing 2000000 bytes of random data, yet your ungzip'd file is ~4.8M bytes long.

Comment: @amit: note that the gzip can reclaim most of the space used by the encoding, but not all.

Comment: what's so awful with the fact gzip can compress a randomly generated bitstring ? gzip is designed to be used on a kind of input but not restricted to ... the probability a random bit string generator produces a compressible one is not 0

Comment: @KeithRandall Thanks for making it more precise.